# Why my CSS3 animation's perfonrmance so slow in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, animation, css

This animation in Google Chrome uses 50% CPU! How can I optimize it?

Backgrouds (PNG24 with transparency) are 30KB and the size of 1440px to ~400px.

```
/* animation */

.animatedClouds1 {
    background:
        url('img/clouds1.png') repeat-x 0 20px;
}

.animatedClouds3 {
    background:
        url('img/clouds3.png') repeat-x 0 250px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wind1  {
         0% {background-position:0px 20px;}
        100% {background-position:1440px 20px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes wind3  {
         0% {background-position:0px 250px;}
        100% {background-position:1440px 250px;}
}

.animatedClouds1
{
    -webkit-animation: wind1 80s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: wind1 80s linear infinite;
    animation: wind1 80s linear infinite;
}

.animatedClouds3
{
    -webkit-animation: wind3 160s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: wind3 160s linear infinite;
    animation: wind3 160s linear infinite;
}
```

Classes `.animatedClouds1` and `.animatedClouds2` have a length of the browser window.

I can't create a sample page but the same problem I saw here http://goo.gl/lNB0D.

Comment: Could you create a sample page/fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, but I can'n. I edited the question and I added example.

Answer (score 0):

I would triage this:

- Step 1: Remove the repeat-x and see the impact
- Step 2: Change from background image to just regular images, see the impact
- Step 3: Change from position to using a translate3D transform, see the impact

CSS Animations aren't the most CPU friendly, but they shouldn't be as bad as that